# QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint bug when trying to scale image

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have created my own class by extending QGraphicsItem and I want to make it so that when someone does a wheel even while over this item, it scales.

This way, i can have multiple items in a scene, and scale each of them in and out as I please.

The problem is, I want the item to scale under the mouse cursor, much like google maps does. That is, a move forward will keep panning the image and scaling it, so taht the area in the vicinity around my mouse pointer is always in view.

```
void ImagePixmapItem::wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event ){

    update();
    qreal factor = 1.2;
    if (event->delta() < 0)
      factor = 1.0 / factor;

    scale(factor, factor);

    scaleFactor *=factor;
    this->scene()->setSceneRect(0,0,this->boundingRect().width(), this->boundingRect().height());

}
```

This is the code I am using to do the scale. The problem is, it always seems to be scaling from the top left corner. Well, this is undesirable, beacuse if I scale in or out too much, eventually my  area of interest around the mouse pointer has moved off the screen, and I have to either scroll manually or pan to the location, zoom, pan, etc, until i get to the desired level.

I tried to use the  QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint, but no matter what values I put in there, it still seems to scale and such from the top left.

What can I add to that code I posted to get the desired effect?

Comment: Just to clarify..Are you talking about expanding or shrinking an item in the scene graph while keeping other items their original size or zooming the entire view of the scene in and out?

Comment: Items within the scene. This way I can have multiple items in scene, at different levels of zoom

Comment: How do you call setTransformOriginPoint?

Comment: using my QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent :  this->setTransformOriginPoint(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved similar functionality in my Image-Manipulation application (scaling the view and having the area under my mouse stay in place and visible) but I scale the whole graphics-view not a specific item, so I don't know if this code can solve your problem.

Anyway, this is what I do in the constructor of my subclassed QGraphicsView (after I set the scene):

```
setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
setResizeAnchor(AnchorViewCenter);
```

I also use the above functions, after each call to:
   MyGraphicsView->setTransform(transform);

I'm not sure if this can help you, but I hope so.